# Uppercase Function with Special Characters Python

Tags: python

I'm writing an extremely simple program for personal use so that I can convert lowercase strings to uppercase. However, I run into a problem when I have special characters e.g. parentheses '()' Is there a way to ignore all special characters, but still have them print? For example if I pass in (hello), I would like to receive (HELLO). My code is:

```
import sys, re
upper_case = []
lower_case = sys.argv[1:]
for word in lower_case:
        upper_case.append(word.upper())

for item in upper_case:
    print item,
```

Comment: That works great on my computer.  Is something not working on yours?

Comment: I get command not found errors when I have special characters like & * ( etc. in my argv string input

Comment: Wrap quotes around what you are passing as an argument `python foo.py "(hello)"` will result in `(HELLO)`

Comment: Thanks @idjaw--is there a way to do it without including quotes? Ideally, I will run this program when I want to convert long strings of text from lowercase to uppercase, without the hassle of modifying anything manually

Comment: That isn't a problem with Python.  That is because of how you are passing the arguments.  In bash `&`, `(`, `)`, etc. are special characters.  If you are going to pass an argument that includes those special characters, you should put quotation marks around it.

Comment: @Izzy what zondo just wrote is the explanation you are looking for as to why you need to use quotes for the behaviour you are looking to support.

Comment: I see, thanks @zondo. So if instead of inputting a string in the command line, I passed it through an input file that should work? So there's no way I can paste in terminal and avoid bash errors?

Comment: The shell will probably also let you escape those special characters with `\ ` instead of using quotes. Double quotes may not be enough depending on what special characters are in the string (e.g. `$` will be a problem).

Comment: Using an input file should work, yes.  You can't just paste into the terminal those special characters.  You would either have to put the arguments in quotation marks, or put a backslash before each special character.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider having the program prompt you for the string. This would avoid any problem with "special characters" involving your operating system:

```
#! python3
while True:
    lcstring = input("\nText?> ")
    print("\n",lcstring.upper())
```

I included a couple of extra newlines to make it easier to copy/paste with a mouse.